# CURL parameters need to be encoded

Tags: curl

Does anyone have a working example of making a CURL call that includes the @ symbol in the data that isn't a file...

Currently i am trying this and it is trying to read the password parameter as a file.  i have tried to use the --data-raw option and that returns a warning that i can only select one http request and then it just fails.

here is an example of what i am trying to do:

```
curl.exe -i -k -F username=abc -F password=@password -F file=@C:\file.pdf https://somepath.php
```

i need to be able to pass the @ in the password.

Thank you
J

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to encode your special character. Replace your `@` character with `%40`.